# Using setRGB() method in BufferedImage

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedreader

I can sucessfully read and write values to an image file which accurately shows an image created.

I simply read the values using getRGB(), and then bit shift them into red, green and blue arrays respectively. Then I simply set them back into another BufferedImage object using the setRGB() method.

Now, I am trying to alter the pixel values, say the very first pixel of the red array. I then print out the first 5 pixels of the red array and the first value is changed as expected before invoking the setRGB() method, but when I read in that image again the first value is now back to its original value?

Does anybody know that using the setRGB() only changes the values in memory, but does not actually write that altered values?

EDITS - THIS IS A SAMPLE REPRESENTATION OF MY CODE (this works perfectly due to getting back an image)

```
//READ IN IMAGE
BufferedImage imgBuf =null;
imgBuf = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));

int w = imgBuf.getWidth();
int h = imgBuf.getHeight();
int[] RGBarray = imgBuf.getRGB(0,0,w,h,null,0,w);

//BIT SHIFT VALUES INTO ARRAY
for(int row=0; row<h; row++)
      {
         for(int col=0; col<w; col++)
         {
            alphaPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[g]>>24)&0xff);
            redPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[g]>>16)&0xff);
            greenPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[g]>>8)&0xff);
            bluePixels[row][col] = (RGBarray[g]&0xff);
            g++;
         }
      }

//BIT SHIFT VALUES BACK TO INTEGERS
for(int row=0; row<h; row++)
{
    for(int col=0; col<w; col++)
    {
        int rgb = (alphaPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 24 | (redPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 16 | (greenPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 8 | (bluePixels[row][col] & 0xff);
        imgBuf.setRGB(col, row, rgb);
     }
}

//WRITE IMAGE BACK OUT
ImageIO.write(imgBuf, "jpeg", new File("new-test.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Write where? If you change the RGB value of the BufferedImage's raster, then yes the memory value is written to and changed. If you mean does it change it to disk? No, not unless you write the image yourself to disk, often with `ImageIO.write(...)`. Changes to the memory representation of disk data will not mathemagically change the disk representation on it's own; instead you have to explicitly do this with your code. I think that you may be missing this last important step.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> Currently I can write to an image created on disk with a new name. So if that works, then surely changing a few values should be the same effect? (Using setRBG() )

I'm still not clear on this. Say for instance:

- If you have an image on disk, say imageA.jpg,
- and say you read this into a BufferedImage via `ImageIO.read(...)`, say into the bufferedImageA variable,
- and then you change the data raster via `setRGB(...)`
- and then write your changed BufferedImage to disk with `ImageIO.write(...)`, say to a new file, imageB.jpg,
- Then if you read in imageB.jpg, it should show the changes made.
- But if you re-read in the unchanged imageA.jpg file, it will remain unchanged.

Comment: Currently I can write to an image created on disk with a new name. So if that works, then surely changing a few values should be the same effect? (Using setRBG() )

Comment: @DouglasGrealis: please clarify your statement above as I'm have a great deal of difficulty understanding it. You are showing no code in your original question, so we have no idea of what you might actually be doing.

Comment: I have edited my last comment. Plus I am using the write() method that takes in an BuffereImage object with the values being set with setRBG() ?

Comment: @DouglasGrealis: I'm sorry, but I'm still not clear. Please see the edit to my answer. Please try to spell out exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Yes I understand that. That is exactly what I have. Only I have two BufferedImage variables. I use one to read in the image values, and then I use the other one to write the values back using the arrays. This works OK. But when I try to change the values in the array before writing them back to disk, it remains unchanged ? (And of course I then read the altered image)

Comment: @DouglasGrealis: In order for us to fully understand what you are experiencing, it would be best if we could experience the difficulties for ourselves. I wonder if it would be advantageous for you to create and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please have a look at the link.

Comment: OK, I have re-edited my post. Bear in mind this code works. But changing values doesn't change. (Of course reading new-test.jpg)

Comment: @DouglasGrealis: for me to test this code, I would have to use your code to create my own [minimal, complete, and verifiable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which I don't have time for. If you're still stuck, and no one has answered you in a bit, again I suggest that you consider putting in the time to create this construct. It's usually well worth the effort. Good luck!

Comment: Oh I see. But this code works. I am just asking is the technique in bit shifting the values into arrays correct? I'm not asking you to test it, just a quick review on it. THanks